# Outputting new R code from within R

Tags: r

I am distributing an R code script for a demonstration, and need to edit the raw data embedded within the script. The data is entered into a series of numerical vectors, which get loaded into a data frame. Problem is, the raw data is also my experimental data, and I would rather not disseminate it.

It is easy enough to transform the data once it is loaded into R. However, I want to output that transformed data in a format that I can easily copy/paste back into my original source code in place of the original data. I think I can do this with a combination of paste() and gsub() within a forloop iterating through the data frame, but I was wondering if there might an easier way. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) had me looking at the dump() function, but I haven't figured out how to make it work yet. Any other ideas? Thanks!

As an illustration, here is the format my code is in:

```
> dat1<-c(4,6,7,8,2,4,5,9)
> dat2<-c(7,7,6,7,8,5,5,4)
> df<-data.frame(dat1,dat2)
> df
  dat1 dat2
1    4    7
2    6    7
3    7    6
4    8    7
5    2    8
6    4    5
7    5    5
8    9    4
```

After transforming the data, I need to output the contents of `df` in a format that I can insert into the source code in place of `dat1<-c(4,6,7,8,2,4,5,9)`

Comment: Are you looking for `dput`?

Comment: yes that is it exactly! Thanks! BTW can you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dput` "writes an ASCII text representation of an R object"

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(dat1 = c(4, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 9), dat2 = c(7, 
7, 6, 7, 8, 5, 5, 4)), .Names = c("dat1", "dat2"), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

```
> rm(df)
> df <- structure(list(dat1 = c(4, 6, 7, 8, 2, 4, 5, 9), dat2 = c(7, 
+ 7, 6, 7, 8, 5, 5, 4)), .Names = c("dat1", "dat2"), row.names = c(NA, 
+ -8L), class = "data.frame")
> df
  dat1 dat2
1    4    7
2    6    7
3    7    6
4    8    7
5    2    8
6    4    5
7    5    5
8    9    4
```